# Sequence object blocking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

We have been experiencing an issue with a sequence object we have that is called a lot. It is used to assign a value prior to a record being inserted into a table.

Today I saw that 700+ sessions (all trying to get the next value from the sequence object) were being blocked by a session that was trying to get the next value from the sequence object with a wait type of PAGELATCH_EX. The other 700+ sessions were waiting on LATCH_EX.

When I looked into the wait resource it was referring to sys.sysobjvalues.

I'm curious as to why this may be happening and if other people have seen this. We recently changed the CACHE value for this sequence from the DEFAULT (50) to 200. I assumed this would improve the performance of calling the sequence given we use it so heavily but possibly I was wrong.

We are using SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Comment: Originally I was thinking of 1000 when I first started looking into the issue. Losing numbers in the event of a crash is not a concern, so I just wanted some validation as to whether there could have been anything else to consider. It makes sense to me that the cache should be set to something like 1000 given how frequently we use it.

Comment: So I made the change to up the value for CACHE to 1000 and I haven't yet seen any blocking regarding the sequence object. I did see a large-ish spike in waits around the usual time for PREEMPTIVE_XE_DISPATCHER but I'm assuming that is coincidental.

Comment: Great! I'll post as an answer if you'd like to accept pending further issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The other 700+ sessions were waiting on LATCH_EX....We recently changed the CACHE value for this sequence from the DEFAULT (50) to 200.

If you've got 700 waiting sessions, my first thought is that the cache needs to be much higher given the workload. I would recommend trying something in the range of 500-1000 (and maybe keep increasing) until you see the waits either stabilize or drop off. There should be a sweet spot you can find with a larger cache value.